# this.id not passing through function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've read similar questions and tried a few different things but nothing has worked so far.

I am trying to use the id of a div, to call a variable and play a sound.

```js
let kick = new Howl({
  src: ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/377560/kick.WAV']
});

$(".pad").click(function(e){
    
var target = e.target.id;
console.log(this.id);
target.play();

  
})
```

```css
.pad {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    background: #594F4D;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1px;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.12/howler.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pad" id="kick"></div>
```

Comment: You assign `target` a string (the id), so it doesn't have a `.play()` function property...? It kind of sounds like you're looking for `eval`, but don't do that

Comment: But the ID is being printed to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what I understand from the question and code snippet is that you have a variable name same as the id of an HTML element, and you want to trigger the play method of the variable which matches the id.

A better way to keeping this information would be by using the data attribute, something like

```
<div class="pad" data-id="kick"></div>
```

But for now I am just giving a solution with id

First what you should do is keep all your instance created with new Howl into an object

```
let Howls = {};
Howls.kick = new Howl({
  src: ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/377560/kick.WAV']
});
// similarly add other sounds
```

Then in your click handler do this

```
$(".pad").click(function(e){        
var target = e.target.id;
if(Howls[target]){
 Howls[target].play();    
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `target.play` with `kick.play`

```js
let kick = new Howl({
  src: ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/377560/kick.WAV']
});

$(".pad").click(function(e){
    
var target = e.target.id;
console.log(this.id);
kick.play();

  
})
```

```css
.pad {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    background: #594F4D;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1px;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.12/howler.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pad" id="kick"></div>
```

Comment: While this works, I will have multiple pads with multiple id's and wanted to be able to fetch a specific pads id and pass it through the play function. Rather than writing seperate click events for each pad.

Answer (score 0):

Use [eval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) :

```js
let kick = new Howl({
  src: ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/377560/kick.WAV']
});

$(".pad").click(function(e){
    
var target = e.target.id;
console.log(this.id);
eval(target).play();

  
})
```

```css
.pad {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 40px;
    width: 55px;
    background: #594F4D;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 1px;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.12/howler.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pad" id="kick"></div>
```